# PHP Addon support N no of Classes finally extend to one class

Tags: php, class, open-source

I am working on a open source project.

My code should support addons features.

I have 6 to 7 client handling classes which finally extend to one class called "clients"

```
class client1{}

class client2 extends client1{}//contacts

class client3 extends client2{}//files

...

class clients extends client9{}//msging
```

This is not proper way to do.(still finding for better way)

This script should support addons. Say one addon having few classes

```
class clientUserManagement{}
```

Then it should be controllable in

```
class clients{}
```

Each class handling different areas of client system.
Right now extending all the class to one class. By using method_exist(), calling the required functionality.

**Important**

- These classes doesn't share any attribute.
- All client related functions should be grouped by type in separate files.
- If all classes are finally controlled under one classes name, using method_exist() it   will be secure to run only client related functions.

Which is the better way to structure it, so that it support addon functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should split things up to encapsualte functionality and then make the classes interact with each other. I would also abstract away basic things to more generic classes that will be used elsewhere.

Client

- has a Collection of Contacts - ClientContactCollection
- has a Collection  of Files - ClientFileCollection
- has a Collection of messages - ClientMessageCollection

ClientContact

- extends a generic Contact

ClientFile

- extends a generic File

ClientMessage

- extends a generic Message